# Azure CLI Passing Value To Other Azure Command

Tags: azure, azure-cli

Was wondering if there's a way to chain az cli command together and how they should work?

For example, I am trying to pipe one `az storage account` command output into another

Also the `az storage account list` command can return multiple values

```
az storage account list --subscription '<subscription>' --query "<query>" |
    az storage account update --name @ --allow-blob-public-access false
```

The above doesn't seem to work, and was wondering if there's a proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way to do this would probably be using [`xargs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) and setting the `--output` argument of your `az storage account list` call to `tsv`.

```
az storage account list --subscription '<subscription>' --query "<query>" --output tsv |
 xargs -I{} az storage account update --name {} --allow-blob-public-access false
```

`xargs -I` allows you to specify a placeholder string (`{}`) that can then be used as an input item in the rest of the `xargs` call.

This should allow you to perform this `update` operation on all the items outputted by your query if multiple values are returned.